# Concatenate two lines if they are not empty

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to combine 2 lines of text into one, but only when they are both not empty lines. For example:

```
1:1 Bob drives his car.
1:2 Bob and his wife are going on a trip. 
They will have an awesome time on the beach.
```

I want to put them into a dictionary like this:

```
dict[1:1] gives me "Bob drives his car."
and dict[1:2] must give me "Bob and his wife are going on a trip.They will have an awesome time on the beach."
```

I know how to fix the fist one (`dict[1:1]`), but I have no idea how I can take the two sentences together.

Or is there an option that if a sentence is followed by another one you can put them on one line? This is just an example in reality , the file contains 100000 lines.

Comment: Are the annotations of `1:1` in the file itself?

Comment: Yes , They  are.
It goes from 1:1 to 1:25, then from 2:1 tot 2:25.
And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this - read one line at a time from the file, and where there is a blank line trigger the start of a new section.

```
start_new_section = True
key = None
output = {}
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line == '':
            start_new_section = True
        elif start_new_section:
            words = line.split(' ')
            key = words[0]
            output[key] = ' '.join(words[1:])
            start_new_section = False
        else:
            output[key] += line

print(output)
```

Or a tidier version of the same idea:

```
key = None
output = {}
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line:
            key = None
        elif key:
            output[key] += line
        else:
            key, _, output[key] = line.partition(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible way you might tackle this problem is to go through your file once and make a list of indices that start with a numerical value. Then you can use the indices to create your dictionary because you know that every 2 numbers in your indices contains one item that should be inserted into your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file is small enough that you can read the entire thing into memory, you can use regular expressions to parse the blocks.  Here's an [example in action](https://regex101.com/r/uL9nV6).

```
import re

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    txt = f.read()

matches = re.findall(r'^(\d+:\d+) (.+?)$(?=(?:\s^\d+:\d+)|\z)', txt, flags=re.M | re.S)
d = {m[0]: m[1].replace(r'\n', '') for m in matches}
```

Comment: Yes that could do the job. But actually the problem is more sofisticated then my examples. But can I run a code like this  just to kind of refactor the file.
So the file  becomes:

`> 1:1 Bob drives his car.
> 
> 1:2 Bob and his wife are going on a trip. They will have an awesome time on the beach.
>`

Comment: How is your file more sophisticated?  Does your file actually contain the `> ` characters on every line?

Comment: No the ">" , stands for the begin of a line.
But is it possible to change the file. So two lines after each other without a newline between them. Will be changed into one line?

Comment: Yes, it assumes all text blocks are separated by 2 newlines.

Comment: They are actually only separated by 1 newline.
Like this
1:1 Some text
[NEWLINE]
1:2 Some text
Text also part of 1:2

Comment: Hmm, next time, you should probably not post an example that's entirely different from the the actual problem.  I updated my answer to handle it without newlines between the blocks.